# Maximum $n$-dimensional volume of set satisfying $(\forall x) \: (\forall y) \: (\| x - y \| \le 1)$

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a set satisfying the property:
$$P(S) \equiv (\forall x \in S) \: (\forall y \in S) \: (\| x - y \| \le 1) $$
where $\| \cdot \|$ is the Euclidean norm.

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a set of all maximal sets $S$ (maximal by set inclusion) s.t. $S$ satisfies the property $P(S)$. Then what is the value of $V = \max_{T \in \mathcal{S}} \operatorname{vol}(T) $ where $\operatorname{vol}(\cdot)$ represents the $n$-dimensional volume of a set.

I can't figure out the shape of the set for even $n=2$, is it a circle with radius $\frac{1}{2}$, or a square with side $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, I can't tell.

Comment: What is the norm? L2 or L1? Your two guesses correspond to one or the other.

Comment: Isn't this just a hypersphere of diameter $1$?  If so, the formula for a hypersphere is very well known.

Comment: @BenjaminWang Euclidean, so L2.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork How can I formally show it is a hypersphere?

Comment: I tried to formally prove it last night by first arguing **Claim 1**: For all $S\in\mathcal{S}$, there exists $x,y\in S$ such that $\|x-y\|_2=1$. But then I found that equally hard as the original question :(

Comment: @Kaind did you have any extra ideas after you posted the question?

Comment: @BenjaminWang Nothing significant... clearly the condition that the set must be maximal is useless, as maximizing the volume takes care of that (if we restrict ourselves to Lebesgue measurable sets only). I should think that even a proof for n = 2 would be siginificant, as it would give ideas which could be extended for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Conjecture: it's the intersection of $n+1$ balls of radius 1 whose centers are all at distance 1 from each other.

Comment: @Karl 1) That's not even a circle with diameter 1. 2) In $\mathbb{R}^2$, atmost 3 points satisfy $\forall x \forall y ||x - y|| = 1$.

Comment: Right, in $\Bbb R^2$ it's a triangle with curved edges, in $\Bbb R^3$ it's a tetrahedron with curved edges, etc. Is this suboptimal?

Comment: @Karl It is suboptimal in $\mathbb{R}^2$, for the area of the rounded triangle is $\frac{\pi - \sqrt{3}}{2} < \frac{\pi}{4}$, which is the area of a circle with diameter $1$.

Comment: I see. I should've checked before posting my guess!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I am making a stupid mistake, this seems to follow from the isodiametric inequality.
A closed ball $B$ of diameter one is a maximal set, since any set $S$ that
strictly contains $B$ would have diameter bigger than one.

Now, the isodiametric inequality says that if $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a
Lebesgue measurable set, then
$$
\operatorname*{vol}\left(  E\right)  \leq\alpha_{n}\left(  \frac
{\text{$\operatorname*{diam}$}E}{2}\right)  ^{n},
$$
where $\alpha_{n}$ is the volume of the ball of radius 1. A proof of this
inequality can be found in the book of [Evans and Gariepy](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/mono/10.1201/b18333/measure-theory-fine-properties-functions-revised-edition-lawrence-craig-evans-ronald-gariepy) and uses Steiner
symmetrization. There is another proof that uses the [Brunn-Minkowski
inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brunn%E2%80%93Minkowski_theorem). I can add this proof if you want, I have it typed up.

Now, if $S$ is any other maximal set, then $\operatorname*{diam}S\leq1$, and
so
$$
\operatorname*{vol}\left(  S\right)  \leq\alpha_{n}\left(  \frac
{\text{$\operatorname*{diam}S$}}{2}\right)  ^{n}\leq\alpha_{n}\left(  \frac
{1}{2}\right)  ^{n}=\operatorname*{vol}\left(  B\right)  .
$$
Hence, the maximum volume is $\alpha_{n}\left(  \frac{1}{2}\right)  ^{n}$ and
it is realized by $B$.

---

**Remark**: Fix $\theta\in\left(  0,1\right)  $. By
replacing $E$ with $\theta E$ and $F$ with $\left(  1-\theta\right)  F$ in the Brunn-Minkowski inequality and
using the $n$-homogeneity of the Lebesgue measure we obtain that
\begin{align*}
\theta\left(  \operatorname*{vol}\left(  E\right)  \right)  ^{\frac{1}{n}
}+\left(  1-\theta\right)  \left(  \operatorname*{vol}\left(  F\right)
\right)  ^{\frac{1}{n}} &  =\left(  \operatorname*{vol}\left(  \theta
E\right)  \right)  ^{\frac{1}{n}}+\left(  \operatorname*{vol}\left(  \left(
1-\theta\right)  F\right)  \right)  ^{\frac{1}{n}}\\
&  \leq\left(  \operatorname*{vol}\left(  \theta E+\left(  1-\theta\right)
F\right)  \right)  ^{\frac{1}{n}}.
\end{align*}
Thus the function $f\left(  t\right)  :=\left(  \operatorname*{vol}\left(
tE+\left(  1-t\right)  F\right)  \right)  ^{`\frac{1}{n}}$ is concave in
$\left[  0,1\right]  $.

**Proof of the isodiametric inequality**.
It is enough to prove the isodiametric inequality for bounded sets, since
otherwise the right-hand side is infinite. If $\lambda>0$, we have that
$\operatorname*{vol}\left(  \lambda E\right)  =\lambda^{n}\operatorname*{vol}
\left(  E\right)  $ and $\left(  \operatorname*{diam}\left(  \lambda E\right)
\right)  ^{n}=\lambda^{n}\operatorname*{diam}$$E$, so without loss of
generality we may assume that $\operatorname*{diam}$$E=1$.

Also, since $\operatorname*{diam}\left(  E\right)  =\operatorname*{diam}%
\left(  \overline{E}\right)  $, we can replace $E$ with $\overline{E}$ and so
we can assume that $E$ is compact. Let
$$
F:=\left\{  -\boldsymbol{x}:\,\boldsymbol{x}\in E\right\}  .
$$
Then $F$ is compact,  $E+F$ is compact, and so it is Lebesgue measurable. By
the previous remark the function $f\left(  t\right)  :=\left(  \mathcal{L}%
^{n}\left(  tE+\left(  1-t\right)  F\right)  \right)  ^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is
concave in $\left[  0,1\right]  $, and so
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(  \operatorname*{vol}\left(  E\right)  \right)  ^{\frac{1}
{n}}+\frac{1}{2}\left(  \operatorname*{vol}\left(  F\right)  \right)
^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq\left(  \operatorname*{vol}\left(  \frac{1}{2}E+\frac{1}
{2}F\right)  \right)  ^{\frac{1}{n}}.
$$
But $\operatorname*{vol}\left(  F\right)  =\operatorname*{vol}\left(
E\right)  $, and so the previous inequality becomes
$$
\operatorname*{vol}\left(  E\right)  =\operatorname*{vol}\left(  F\right)
\leq\operatorname*{vol}\left(  \frac{1}{2}E+\frac{1}{2}F\right)  .
$$
If $\boldsymbol{x}\in\frac{1}{2}E+\frac{1}{2}F$, then $\boldsymbol{x}
=\frac{\boldsymbol{x}^{\prime}-\boldsymbol{x}^{\prime\prime}}{2}$, where
$\boldsymbol{x}^{\prime},\boldsymbol{x}^{\prime\prime}\in E$, and so
$$
\Vert\boldsymbol{x}\Vert=\frac{1}{2}\Vert\boldsymbol{x}^{\prime}%
-\boldsymbol{x}^{\prime\prime}\Vert\leq\frac{1}{2},
$$
which shows that $\frac{1}{2}E+\frac{1}{2}F\subseteq\overline{B\left(
0,\frac{1}{2}\right)  }$. Hence,
$$
\operatorname*{vol}\left(  E\right)  \leq\operatorname*{vol}\left(  \frac
{1}{2}E+\frac{1}{2}F\right)  \leq\operatorname*{vol}\left(  \overline{B\left(
0,\frac{1}{2}\right)  }\right)  =\frac{\alpha_{n}}{2^{n}}.
$$

Comment: Yes, this most certainly does prove it (I've never heard about the isodiametric inequality), could you add a proof to it?

Comment: I just added a proof. I am not proving the Brunn-Minkowski inequality since there is a nice proof on the Wikipedia link

Answer (score -2):

Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfy:
$P(S) \equiv (\forall x \in S) \: (\forall y \in S) \: (\| x - y \|_2 \le 1) $. Define the notation $B_n(r,p)=$ the $n$-dimensional hyperball with radius $r$, centre $p$.

Let $M=\{S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n: [P(S)=\top] \wedge [\nexists S'\in\mathbb{R}^n \text{ s.t. } (P(S')=\top) \wedge (S'\supsetneq S)]\}$. **Claim:** $V := \max_{T \in M} \operatorname{vol}(T) =\operatorname{vol}(B_n(1/2, 0))$.

Note: This problem seems intuitively easy but deceptively hard. I attach my wrong proof in the hope that someone can fix it. The $\color{red}{red}$ implication doesn't hold, so the proof is invalid.

**$\color{red}{Wrong}$ Proof:** Note that it is sufficient to prove that $M=A$, where we define $A:=\{B_n(1/2,p): p\in\mathbb{R}^n\}$. It is obvious that $A\subseteq M$. Now we try to prove $M\subseteq A$:

Given $S\in M$, so that $P(S)=\top$ and $S$ is maximal. Note that $P(S)=\top\color{red}{\nRightarrow} \exists$ $p$ such that there is a circumscribed $B_n(1/2,p)\supseteq S$. But maximality implies that there must be equality, so $S=B_n(1/2,p)$. Thus, $S\in A$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: The same mistake (as in a deleted answer). The fact that $\| x - y \|_2 \le 1$ for $x,y\in S$ **doesn't imply** that $S$ is contained in a ball of diameter $1$ (consider an equilateral triangle with side $1$ in the 2D case).

Comment: @metamorphy oh lord